# How to programmatically add root folder to the path for every script?

Tags: python, import, python-import, relative-import

The file structure I currently have is something like:

```
__init__.py
script_folder
    __init__.py
    s1.py
    s2.py
b_folder
    __init__.py
    b1.py
    b2.py
lib_folder
    __init__.py
    lib1.py
    libb2.py
```

Files in `b_folder` can use the files from `lib_folder`, and the scripts in `script_folder` can use the files from `b_folder` and `lib_folder`. I do imports as follows:

```
from lib_folder.lib1 import func_1
```

Imports from other folders seem to work if I add

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '.')
```

to **every single file** that does an import from another folder. Like this, it all works. But this repetitive line pollutes my code.

I wonder if there is a way to add the root folder to the path project-wide, or directory-wide, without having to add any magic line to every file that needs to import something from another folder?

Changing `$PATH` on my computer is not a good solution for me because the code is supposed to run on other machines.

I have tried to add `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '.')` to all `__init__.py`, but it does not seem to make any difference.

My `launch.json` (in Visual Studio Code) is as below:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "args": ["-m"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way and it is actually the canonical way of running python scripts. You must run the scripts as parts of the package they belong to from the root dir - so in your case remove the top level init py (the top folder is not a package), remove all the sys.path lines (this can lead to hair pulling bugs) and:

```
$ ls
lib_folder b_folder script_folder
$ python -m script_folder.b1 # note this is not a filesystem notation
```

Running this way python will add all your top level packages on the path and imports will function correctly.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it did not work so far. 

I am using Visual Studio code, added  ` "args": ["-m"], ` to a basic launch.json, getting an error `Cannot find lib_folder` unless I have `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '.')`

Comment: Will try to create the minimal example and try and get it to work when I have time.

Comment: @YuliaV I would recommend PyCharm for python - does VS have run configurations? Specify  the -m switch there - and change the working dir to the roott dir (should be the project dir) there

Comment: ideally, the library I am developing should work on any machine, without the user having to modify the $PATH, going into advanced settings of the editor etc. This is why I was asking for the programmatic solutions :)

Comment: yes, VSC has this configuration, I have added  added ` "args": ["-m"], ` to a basic launch.json, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging for the general info

Comment: @YuliaV this is the programmatic way :) User has _not_ to modify the path, they should just run from the parent dir - usually however automatic run configurations launch the script from the script dir (an anti-pattern in python) - that is why you sshould specify this manually. Also just adding `-m` is not enough - you run now not `python package/module.py` but `python -m package.module` - note no py or filesystem separators

Comment: In the link above in the image https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/python/debugging/debug-configurations.png it has an option "Module: debug a python module by invoking it with -m". - that's the one!! Make sure to specify correct (project) working dir

Comment: and so I did, and it does not work!

Comment: Can you post me a screen of your config @YuliaV

Comment: posted! BTW thanks for looking into my problem :)

Comment: Thanks - when you run this what is. the working dir? What is the generated command line? - working dir should be the root of the packages and command should be as in the answer - can you try that on a terminal to make sure that works?

Comment: will do a bit later, need to finish something else urgently. Thanks again for your help!